# NextJS - Prisma - MySQL: Query works for one database table but not for the other

Tags: javascript, mysql, next.js, prisma

I'm running into a strange problem where only one api endpoint is accessible **in production** on Vercel, namely /api/users. I also made /api/posts which is an exact copy but of the table 'posts', but it's giving me 500 Internal error.

I'm using NextJS with Prisma. I migrated the latest change, the MySQL database looks good, the tables and entries are in there.

On localhost, all the endpoints work perfectly, it's only after I upload to Vercel that the endpoints don't work. What am I missing?

/api/users - Works

```
import { PrismaClient } from "@prisma/client";

export default async function handler(req, res) {
  const prisma = new PrismaClient();
  const users = await prisma.user.findMany();
  return res.send(users);
}
```

/api/posts - Doesn't work

```
import { PrismaClient } from "@prisma/client";

export default async function handler(req, res) {
  const prisma = new PrismaClient();
  const users = await prisma.post.findMany();
  return res.send(users);
}
```

schema.prisma

```
// This is your Prisma schema file,
// learn more about it in the docs: https://pris.ly/d/prisma-schema

generator client {
  provider = "prisma-client-js"
}

datasource db {
  provider = "mysql"
  url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
  shadowDatabaseUrl = env("SHADOW_DATABASE_URL")
}

model User {
  id Int @id @default(autoincrement())
  email String @db.VarChar(255)
  password String @db.VarChar(255)
  firstName String @db.VarChar(255) @map("first_name")
  lastName String @db.VarChar(255) @map("last_name")
}

model Post {
  id Int @id @default(autoincrement())
  title String @db.VarChar(255)
  description String @db.VarChar(255)
  order Int @default(10)
}
```

Comment: Can you specify "doesn't work" more closely? Is there an error message? If so, what does it say?

Comment: @some-user /api/posts gives me internal server error (code 500) like I said in the post

Comment: "Internal Server Error" is the error that the API replies to the client via HTTP. You'll have to find out, why your server replies with that. That might be caused by a prisma error or whatever...

Comment: @some-user I just found out the error behind it ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'findMany'). It seems like the Post model isn't recognized by prisma

Comment: Did you run `prisma generate`?